# HttpSessionState null using CassiniDev

Tags: httpsession, cassini-dev

I am trying to build some unit test using CassiniDev.
First of all I create a Server and a Page and generate a request:

```
CassiniDevServer server = new CassiniDevServer();
server.StartServer("C:\\", 8080, "/", "localhost");
File.Delete(@"C:\Default.aspx");
File.Create(@"C:\Default.aspx");
WebClient browser = new WebClient();
browser.DownloadString(server.NormalizeUrl("Default.aspx"));
```

Everything is fine, but when I try to use the HttpSessionState object, it is null:

```
session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
```

Should I do something else or additional steps?